# Example from Deitel Book C: How to program - Need advice

Tags: c

Okay, basically, i need to find the average grade in student's group, without knowing their exact number.

The following code given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    unsigned int counter;
    int grade;
    int total;

    float average;

    total = 0;
    counter = 0;

    printf( "%s", "Enter grade, -1 to end: " );
    scanf( "%d", &grade);

    while (grade != -1)
    {
        total = total + grade;
        counter = counter + 1;

        printf( "%s", "Enter grade, -1 to end: " );
        scanf( "%d", &grade );
    }

    if ( counter != 0 )
    {
        average = (float) total / counter;

        printf( "Class average is %.2f\n", average);
    }

    else
    {
        puts( "No grades were entered" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, this one should give me the class average of any number of entered grades. But whenever i enter random number of grades and then print "-1" to stop the cycle, it prints the message "Class average is 0". No matter how many figures you've entered. The only condition that works properly is when you don't print any grades and print "-1" at once, then "No grades were entered" works here.

Help me please, with that. Because it is either blind me or some serious mistake i can't see. Third variant includes mistake in the book.

Looking forward to your help!

Comment: I assume that the problem might be in "float" type which initializes "average". Just because i've tried this program when "average" was int and it worked properly.

Comment: Cannot reproduce:  http://ideone.com/3fRtxt

Comment: Works fine for me.  Give an example of your input that generates that output.

Comment: okay, then probably it's the question in IDE i'm using, that's Virtual-C IDE which is, i guess, basic. 

Can you advise any good IDE for MAC to use with C? Except, Xcode ofc.
Would be much grateful!

Comment: @DmitryA.: What is the problem with using Xcode ? It would normally be the obvious choice for Mac-based stuff ?

Comment: @AndrewCottrell yah, just hang on a sec

Comment: @PaulR i just thought it might cause me certain troubles though. Probably will follow your advice then, buddy. Thanks! The problem is switching lldb which is preset in latest Xcode to gdb.

Comment: @DmitryA.: for basic debugging there is not much difference between lldb and gdb - it's only the more advanced commands where you start to see differences. Besides, most of the time you can just use the GUI for debugging. Нехай щастить!

Comment: @AndrewCottrell here. http://ideone.com/ZXEajf

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help! My first time here, and so amazed at how people contribute. Thanks!

Comment: @DmitryA.: your example input at http://ideone.com/ZXEajf gives the right answer: 54.45 !

Comment: @PaulR yes, it does, i see it. But i don't think output should be like "Enter the grade, -1 to end: Enter the grade, -1 to end:...." and then it gives the desired answer of "Class average is %.2f"... Ideally, it should give only this message. that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how to use a debugger, you might try that. Sometimes debuggers and interactive programs get along poorly, so you could read the input from a file instead of standard input to make the debugger happy.

If you aren't yet handy with a debugger, a good place to start is to add some debug code to echo the figures you're using. For example, after exiting the loop, add this:

```
printf("counter = %d, total = %d\n", counter, total);
```

One possible problem is in the division particularly if you're using a dubious compiler, as your comment on another reply hints). The precedence for cast is *supposed* to be higher than division, but you might try casting both numbers to float:

```
average = (float) total / (float) counter;
```

You could also try a general `%f` on the results print.

Comment: tried average = (float) total / (float) counter; 

Works perfectly! But hey, what's the point of using float on counter? Counter is a strictly devised integer, i thought it can't have float marks?

correct me if i'm mistaken.

Comment: also, though it provides the class average, i see results like "Class average is 73.00" instead of (following rules of the game) "Class average is 73.15".

Comment: The reason for the `(float)` is to *cast* (convert) the integer values to `float`. When you divide a `float` by an `integer`, the integer is supposed to be *promoted* to `float` before proceeding, but if that doesn't seem to be happening, you can cast both values to `float` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly for me:

```
Enter grade, -1 to end: 5
Enter grade, -1 to end: 5
Enter grade, -1 to end: 4
Enter grade, -1 to end: 3
Enter grade, -1 to end: -1
Class average is 4.25



$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
```

Comment: Thanks! That's much appreciated! I've probably got to use proven compilators and not just use freaking stuff that gives me mistakes though!

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    unsigned int counter;
        int grade;
        int total;
        float average;
        total = 0;
        counter = 0;
        grade = -2;

        fflush(stdin);
        while (grade != -1) {
            printf( "%s", "Enter grade, -1 to end: " );
            scanf( "%d", &grade);
            total = total + grade;
            counter = counter + 1;
        };

        if ( counter != 0 ) {
            average = (float) total / counter;
            printf( "Class average is %.2f\n", average);
        } 
        else {
            puts( "No grades were entered" );
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Like i said, the problem is solved. I might have to think of changing my current IDE

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior according to the C standard.

Comment: fflush() function call is, actually, not needed. To make it sure, I added it. Buffered IO for fflush need string.h header for prototype declaration.

Answer (score -1):

In UNIX/Linux environment, the STDIN keyboard-mapped file IO will be initialized. Therefore, in GCC/G++, it might work.

In Visual C/C++, it might not work.

Issue:

- Firstly, in strict coding, your C variable, grade, should get grade value first prior to the while-loop block. That might cause the issue depending on your OS environment.

To make it run on every standard C environment, you will be able to clear the stdard input file system first.